# how to turn off watermark on wonderplugin carousel

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery-plugins, carousel

I am using the wonderplugin free version on my website and I would like to get rid of the wonderplugin link in every alternate image. How can I turn it off?

I have tried changing a bunch of codes but they didn't work. All i want to do is remove the link attached on alternate images. Thank You.

Comment: also in inspect i saw these codes

</div><a href="http://www.wonderplugin.com/wordpress-carousel/" style="text-decoration:none;font:12px Arial,Tahoma,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#333;display:block!important;visibility:visible!important;font-size:12px!important;" target="_blank">WordPress Carousel Free Version</a></div></div>
<divdiv></div></div>

Comment: It's free because of the watermark. If want to get rid of it, then buy the standard version!

Answer (score 0):

Buy Full version to remove this or if you want to use free one try this

As far as free version is concern, the link can be removed by the custom css.

On the edit slider screen of the plugin click on Option tab.

Click on Advance Option and put following css in the Custom CSS box.

```
div.amazingslider-box-1 :nth-child(3) { visibility: hidden;}
```

This will hide the link.

Comment: _"Buy the full version"_ should be the only answer. There is a reason why there is a free version with watermarks...

Comment: that didnt work cos im using the carousel and not the slider. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find **wonderplugincarousel.js** in `..\wonderplugin-carousel-free\wonderplugin-carousel\engine`
2. Find and remove `versionmark:"AMFree",`
3. Find `showwdefault:true` and change to `showwdefault:false` (be near versionmark:"AMFree",)

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I fit this problem like this:

1. Find `wonderplugincarousel.js` in
   `..\wonderplugin-carousel-free\wonderplugin-carousel\engine`
2. Find `this.options.mark="WordPress 3D Carousel Trial Version"`
3. Change to `this.options.mark=""`

I hope it is useful for you